# Механизм работы наследования с++

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

У меня вопрос про механизм работы наследования. Когда мы наследуем классы, друг от друга, то один класс получает доступ к членам другого класса, но это очень упрощенно. Меня интересует более точное определение происходящего при наследовании. Сейчас поясню, что натолкнуло меня на эту мысль. Есть 2 класса:

```
class Parent
{
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void say() 
    {
        cout << "I am child";
    }
};
```

Теперь, самое главное, что меня интересует:

```
int main()
{
    Parent variable = Child();
}
```

Почему работает данная запись и все прекрасно компилируется? Теперь другой момент, если я попытаюсь сделать вот-так:

```
variable.say();
```

То у меня ничего не получится, хотя казалось бы, в `variable` лежит объект класса `Child`, а `Child` в свою очередь имеет метод `say`, но вызвать я его не могу, как так? Объясните пожалуйста, что происходит при наследовании одного класса от другого, явно в класс наследник не просто копируются члены класса-родителя, а это происходит как-то по другому, как?

Comment: *"в variable лежит объект класса Child"* - нет, у `variable` же явно объявлен тип `Parent`.

Comment: @user7860670, тогда почему мы можем проинициализировать его объектом класса Child?

Comment: Он инициализируется экземпляром класса `Parent`, который является подобъектом экземпляра `Child`. Такая ситуация называется object slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как бы это выразиться...

```
Parent variable = Child();
```

скопируется только та часть `Child`а, которая соответствует `Parent`. Почему компилируется? Ну, поскольку `Child` является одновременно `Parent`... :)

Объект `variable` - это просто объект типа `Parent`, со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Заметим, что вы не сможете также сделать

```
Parent * variable = new Child;
variable->say();
```

по той же самой причине - `variable` - это указатель на `Parent`, а никакого `say()` у `Parent` нет. Ни обычного, ни вирптуального.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что и было нужно)